# named parameter type constraints

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, custom-attributes

I am designing a custom attribute class.

```
public class MyAttr: Attribute
{
    public ValueRange ValRange { get; set; }
}
```

Then I am attempting to assign this attribute to a property in an adjoining class:

```
public class Foo
{
    [MyAttr(ValRange= new ValueRange())]
    public string Prop { get; set; }
}
```

However, the compiler is complaining the following:

> 'ValRange' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type

I also tried converting the ValueRange class to a `struct` in hopes that become a value type might solve the problem. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is there any way around this?

No.

For more details I refer you to section 17.1.3 of the C# 4 specification, which I reproduce here for your convenience:

---

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int, long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility.
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.
>
> A constructor argument or public field which does not have one of these types, cannot be used as a positional or named parameter in an attribute specification.

---

Remember, the point of an attribute is to *at compile time* add information to the metadata associated with the entity upon which you've placed the attribute. That means that all the information associated with that attribute must have a well-defined, unambiguous way to serialize it into and out of metadata. By restricting the set of legal types to a small subset of all possible types we ensure that the compiler can always emit legal metadata that the consumer can understand.

Comment: I remember the first time I ran up against this and thought, "Aww.  :("  But then I thought about what the world would be if I actually _could_ have done it, and realized that this limitation makes a _ton_ of sense.

Comment: I didn't find anything proving it but I figured this would be the case. Thank you for the resource. But based upon the documentation ... I could just store it is type Object then cast it when I need to use it in code elsewhere (which is very infrequently). Unfortunately there will be associated overhead but would that not be feasible?

Comment: @Matthew: No. The value you provide for the object field must be known fully at compile time as either a constant of one of the given types, null, a typeof expression, or a single-dimensional array where all the values in it are similarly "known at compile time".  Again, I repeat the key point: the point of an attribute is to add information **to metadata at compile time**.  The **compiler** has to have full knowledge of the information being added.  Attributes are not code that runs when the program runs; they are extra metadata to be stuck into the compiled program.

Comment: ahh, I understand. That makes sense after rethinking it through. I just simply took the class and turned it into an attribute as well and that approach solved the problem.

Comment: "I just simply took the class and turned it into an attribute as well and that approach solved the problem." - For some definition of "solved"?

Answer (score 2):

Attribute parameter values need to be resolvable at compile time (i.e constants).

See [`Attribute Parameter Types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177221.aspx) on MSDN:

> Values passed to attributes must be known to the compiler at compile time.

If you can create a `ValueRange` that is a constant, you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way around this?

Yes.

You can have your attribute use a `Type` property and then use types that implement a defined *interface*, for which the code that processes that attribute would have to *assume*, and as such also create an *implicit*, but hopefully *documented*, requirement to its clients:

```
public interface IValueRange {
  int Start { get; }
  int End { get; }
}
public class MyAttr : Attribute { 
  // The used type must implement IValueRange
  public Type ValueRangeType { get; set; } 
}

// ....

public class Foo { 

  class FooValueRange : IValueRange {
    public int Start { get { return 10; } }
    public int End { get { return 20; } }
  }
  [MyAttr(ValueRangeType = typeof(FooValueRange))]
  public string Prop { get; set; }

}
```

This is not unlike many classes in the `System.ComponentModel` namespace, like [`DesignerAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zas7k9h(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Attribute parameters must be values [of the following types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288454%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (quoting the article):

- Simple types (bool, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double)
- string
- System.Type
- enums
- object (The argument to an attribute parameter of type object must be a constant value of one of the above types.)
- One-dimensional arrays of any of the above types

Edit: Changed "compile-time constant" to "value", since types and arrays are not constants (thanks to the commenter who pointed this out (and subsequently deleted his comment for some reason...))

Answer (score 1):

Attributes can only receive compile-time-constants as parameters (e.g. 3, "hello", typeof(MyClass), "path to a resource defining whatever non constant data you need").

The last example (passing a type) I gave may help you design a workaround (pass a type implementing an interface with the method you need).