# Datatype.Date how to set minimum date to Today?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a datepicker using MVC5 DataType.Date:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public DateTime ArrivalDate { get; set; }
```

How can I set the minimum available date to Today and disable all past dates?

Alternatively, is there an option to disable a custom range of dates?

I have tried to create a custom DateRangeValidator using the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182606/asp-mvc-5-client-validation-for-range-of-datetimes), but with that I get the following error: [named parameter type constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809755/named-parameter-type-constraints)

Here's my Date range validator:

```
public DateTime FirstDate = DateTime.Today.Date;
    //public DateTime SecondDate { get; set; }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(DateTime date, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // your validation logic
        if (date >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(FirstDate))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Date is not valid.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try building a custom [`ValidationAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute) with your own logic :

```cs
public sealed class PresentOrFutureDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // your validation logic
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(value) >= DateTime.Today)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Past date not allowed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use an object for value? `Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'System.DateTime'`

Comment: It's an override so we must follow parent signature. Work on the object to cast/convert it to the expected type.